# .GroupBy with .Take VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ienumerable

I am interested in filtering some data on several different criteria.  When I pull my list from the database, I currently have two `.Where` clauses, one `.GroupBy`, and one `.Take`.  My issue is I want to take 3 from each group and add it to my list, which ultimately shouldn't be a grouped list.

Here is some code I've been working with:

```
Dim dateRangeEnd As New Date(Property.Year, 10, 31)
Dim configurableCount = 3
Dim unfilteredList = _repository.GetIEnumerableFromDB(param1, param2) _
    .Where(Function(r) ({status1, status2, status3}) _
    .Any(Function(x) r.status.HasValue AndAlso x = r.status.Value)) _
    .Where(Function(r) r.StartDate.Value.Year = Property.Year AndAlso r.StartDate.Value < dateRangeEnd) _
    .GroupBy(Function(r) r.StartDate.Value.Month) _
    .Take(configurableCount)
```

How can I edit this so that I adding only the `configurableCount` from each month to my list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You flatten a sequence of sequences with [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534336%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
.Where(Function(r) ({status1, status2, status3}) _
.Any(Function(x) r.status.HasValue AndAlso x = r.status.Value)) _
.Where(Function(r) r.StartDate.Value.Year = Property.Year AndAlso r.StartDate.Value < dateRangeEnd) _
.GroupBy(Function(r) r.StartDate.Value.Month) _
.SelectMany(Function(g) g.Take(configurableCount))
```

Comment: And .SelectMany will pull the configurable amount from each group?  If I understand that is happeneing because the `(Function(g) g.Take(configurableCount))` is selecting from each group?

Comment: `SelectMany` will take everything the selector function returns. The selector function is called once for each element in the outer sequence (which is the sequence of groups), so it calls `Take` on each group separately.